# Google Analytics not working 100% with Magento

Tags: magento, google-analytics, billing, e-commerce

I need to solve a problem that the e-commerce report on analytics page, is showing 30% less sales than the Magento report.

I was wondering where I put the analytics code with the sales transactions? In the success page after the payment?
On our e-commerce, we use a third party billing app that makes the user navigate to another page, and I guess, sometimes the user just doesn't go back to the success page. So I was thinking that this could be the problem.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user doesn't come back, it will be difficult to get an accurate count without that third party service giving you one. If you were to tell Analytics that the "Go to the third party page" screen is a "complete" transaction, you'd have too many sales reported (some people will abort at the payment stage). As you can see with your situation, the opposite happens when you wait for them to return to count a "sale".

Can you add your analytics tracking code at the payment processor's site? Otherwise, I don't think Analytics was build for this case...

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: when the customer goes to the third part page it doesn't mean it will get paid, even on the success page it still doesn't mean it, because the billing software will warn me async about the payment... what to do? =[

Comment: This is more or less outside the realm of Google Analytics, which relies on your pages having some significance in the funnel. If you can't depend on *any* page triggering this, you will need to use some other reporting tool (like Magento itself) for gathering sales statistics.

Comment: This shouldn't stop you from using the funnels/goals to optimize your pages and increase conversion, though. Higher rates of users getting to the pre-payment page will still convert to higher sales, generally speaking.

Comment: so, just to make sure... the google analytics e-commerce js code is printed on the success page?